# Redirect user to own Marketplace page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'd like to let my users go straight to my own dev page on the WP7-Marketplace.
Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to show all your apps rather than just one particular one. In that case, you could use [MarketplaceSearchTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.marketplacesearchtask%28VS.92%29.aspx) and use your publisher name as the search term. I haven't tested this code, but should work.

```
MarketplaceSearchTask mst = new MarketplaceSearchTask();
mst.ContentType = MarketplaceContentType.Applications;
mst.SearchTerms = "your publisher name"
mst.Show();
```